# Integrating Play 2.1 and external game server

Tags: validation, internationalization, playframework, netty, playframework-2.1

I am developing chess playing server based on Java and Netty and client-application using C++. 
Messaging process between client and server is based on Google Protobuf Protocol
Now I want website to act as client for application server so that it would be tightly integrated with server app

I have chosen Play 2.1(JAVA) framework for the website

1)

First i ran into trouble trying to run my Netty server instance from Play 2.1 application so I added next code to Global.java (Play framework startup file )

```
   public void onStart(Application app) {
    // ...
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                new NettyServer().run();
            }
        }.start();
   }
```

Does it seem to be a good idea to run my own instance of Netty this way?

2)
I am not sure how to validate data, as app server gets data to be validated from both C++ client and website by different protocols
Client sends it as binary-encoded data using protobuf protocol and website sends POST requestI want validation to be equal for both clients
For validating data sent from the website I can use Form < T > helper thought i can't use it for binary encoded protobuf data. Any ideas on how to manage validation?

3)
I use Messages.get() from i18n Play module to translate messages to user's language. Client using browser, Play determines user's language from client request headers, and chooses appropriate translations file.

But what about my client? I don't know anything about user's language so i can't send it to my app.
Moreover i didn't manage to find a way to set language manually in Messages.get()